# What does stdout in display_errors in phpinfo() mean?

Tags: security, php

I have 'stdout' under display_errors in my phpinfo.

What does it mean?

Where can I find the documentation about it?

I could not find one in http://php.net/

I read [here](http://www.noupe.com/php/php-security-tips.html) telling that it should be off for the security reasons.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

stdout is the output stream that is used for normal output. echo "hello worl"; outputs to stdout. You can also log to file, or output to stderr. I don't think stderr is useful in the web context, but I could be wrong.

PHP Manual: [`php://` — Accessing various I/O streams - (PHP Wrappers)](http://php.net/wrappers.php)

Comment: stderr is logged to webserver error log by default (at least on apache)

Comment: stdout = "Standard output", stderr = "Standard error [output]"